# Wagtail: How to verify if a user can access a page in the template

Tags: django, templates, permissions, wagtail

I am creating a personal website using **Django with Wagtail**, in which users belonging to different groups can access certain pages. For example, the family group can see my holiday photos, while the co-workers group can see some internal documents.

Setting up permissions access permission is very straightforward through the admin. However, I would like to show a lock next to the link to *forbidden* pages. This will make it very clear to the user which links can be followed and which ones can't.

Is there any way to verify whether the current user has access to a given page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fiddling around with Wagtail's code, I've found that the permissions are handled through a model called `PageViewRestriction` (the [code](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/96965d2a3ae32e2ecfcde5b77c9df1304d663493/wagtail/core/models.py#L2078) is very succinct and clear), which in turns inherits `BaseViewRestriction` that defines a method `accept_request`. Since the page to which is referring is store in the model, the only missing piece is the user requesting access.

With this, I've managed to put together a very simple template tag, which checks whether the current user can see the given page. The filter looks like this:

```py
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def can_view(context, page):
    pvrs = PageViewRestriction.objects.filter(page=page)
    request = context['request']
    if pvrs:
        for pvr in pvrs:
            if pvr.accept_request(request):
                return True
        return False
    return True
```

Which in turn I use in my template like this:

```html
{% can_view menuitem as permission %}
  {% if not permission %}
    <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
  {% endif %}
```

Note that in principle a page can have multiple different permissions specified. For example, members of different groups can view it. I assumed that if the current user belongs to one of those groups, or if the page does not specify view permissions, then the user can access that page.

Comment: Good sleuthing - but note that this will likely generated a *lot* of queries. You may want to consider some sort of strategy to group what is permitted in the user's session, to avoid adding a query for each link on the page.

Comment: I am aware it is a bit of brute-force. I just wanted to give a quick overview of where the information is actually stored (it took me a while to dig through Wagtail's code). I didn't have enough time to think about a more flexible approach. Of course, one can always check the group's the user belongs to, but the logic about having access to a page can be more sophisticated...

Comment: It would be better to use `pvrs = page.get_view_restrictions()`.  This will also get the view restrictions from ancestor pages which also apply.