# Django/Wagtail: How to check if the user has permissions to access a given Page?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm new to Wagtail and it has been an awesome experience so far!

I am trying to solve the following problem:
The user can see a list of all children pages available and, depending if he hasn't permissions to access each page it will show a locker icon, as in the attached picture.

[Wireframe/sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAUhy.png)

I'm using Private Pages, accessible to users in specific groups.

Basically, I have the following piece of code:

```
{% for course in page.get_children %}
<h2> <a href="{{ course.url }} "> {{ course.title }}
    </a>
</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

Is there any property I can check to know if the user has or hasn't permissions for each `course` inside my loop?

My model:

```
from django.db import models
from wagtail.core.models import Page

# Create your models here.
class CoursePage(Page):
    """
    A Page...
    """

    description = models.TextField(
        help_text='Text to describe the course',
        blank=True)

    subpage_types = ['course_module.ModulePage']


class ModulePage(Page):
    description = models.TextField(
        help_text='Text to describe the module',
        blank=True)


    subpage_types = ['lesson.LessonPage']
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see your `models.py`

Comment: Hi Dan, I currently have a very simple model:`

```
from django.db import models
from wagtail.core.models import Page

# Create your models here.
class CoursePage(Page):
    """
    A Page...
    """
    
    description = models.TextField(
        help_text='Text to describe the course',
        blank=True)

    subpage_types = ['course_module.ModulePage']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59022143/wagtail-how-to-verify-if-a-user-can-access-a-page-in-the-template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the request object.  Here is one approach: Check each module for view restrictions in `get_context` and add the list of modules and authorizations to the context.

```
class CoursePage(Page):
    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        modules_list = []
        for module in self.get_children():
            restrictions = module.get_view_restrictions()
            auth = all(restriction.accept_request(request)
                       for restriction in restrictions)
            modules_list.append((module, auth))
        context['modules_list'] = modules_list

        return context
```

In your template you can then use the auth flag to determine if a lock icon should be shown.